# pandas dataframe column to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I expect I have a typo but I can't see it.

```
df = pd.to_datetime(gdf['startdate'], format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

This gives the eroor:

```
ValueError: time data '16/06/2020 09:01:31' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

`gdf['startdate']` looks like this:

```
0      08/06/2020 13:31:14
1      08/06/2020 14:42:45
2      08/06/2020 14:34:13
3      09/06/2020 12:20:41
4      09/06/2020 15:31:36
              ...         

144    29/07/2020 11:36:34
145    30/07/2020 12:31:17
146    31/07/2020 14:27:36
147    31/07/2020 08:21:14
148    06/08/2020 12:08:38
Name: startdate, Length: 149, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched around `%d` and `%m` in your formatting:

```
gdf['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(
    gdf['startdate'], 
    format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
)
```

If a value in your column is not like a datetime at all and causing errors, you can use `errors='coerce'` to set those to `NaT`:

```
gdf['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(
    gdf['startdate'], 
    format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S",
    errors='coerce',
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now this error `ValueError: time data ' ' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S' (match)`

Comment: The error is quite informative: I guess one of the values in your column is not in that format, i guess it has format '  ' as the error says, you can use parameter errors='coerce' if you want to convert this to NaT.

Comment: thanks, that forces it through, although when I try `df.date()` I get:  `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'date'` Ultimately I'm trying to just get the date information cutting out the h:m:s

Comment: df['startdate'] is what you need or? in your example there's no column 'date'

Comment: Ah, got it! `gdf['startdate'].dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")`